# R - meet the condition then continue loop, otherwise repeat

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I now have a vector x, and I want to create another vector y. Its role is to divide x into many groups by comparing the x value with a specific value(e.g 30).

here is the vector x:

```
x <- c(1,2,5,34,21,6,0,56,77,21,3,0)
```

If describe this problem with loops and conditional statements, I think that is:

when the conditions are satisfied, then continue the loop, otherwise repeat the it.

For example, in the vecor x, 1, 2, and 5 is less than 30, so "1" is repeated for three times in y; 34 is greater than 30, so the loop continue to the value of 2, and 21 is less than 30, so "2" is repeated for 1 time, and so on.

The final value of y should be like this:

```
y <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4)
```

Maybe my expression is not very clear, because I am a Non-Native English speaker, and I'm a little confused right now, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: How many times should each number less than 30 be repeated?

Comment: As @RonakShah 's answer demonstrates, in R, often a behavior you might describe with a loop is best produced using the structure of the object instead:)

Comment: Actually, the repeated times correspond to the number of values that satisfy the condition (less than 30) .For example, 1,2,5 correspond to 1,1,1, or 21,6,0 correspond to 2,2,2. @hpesoj626

Comment: It is not easy for me to understand, but you're right.@DanHall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` here and increment the count every time we find a value greater than 30.

```
cumsum(x > 30) + 1
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Ah. I was experimenting with `cumsum` earlier but didn't try `x>30`.